# Database - Version Control - Managing dropped/deleted objects

Tags: sql-server, git, version-control, sql-server-data-tools

We want to clean up our database schema and drop/delete objects which are no longer being used.

We suspect that sometime in the future we'll want to resurrect the removed functionality.

We've discussed the following options for dealing with dropped objects in version control:

1. Deleting the .sql files from source control once they are gone from the database and relying on the version history to store the definitions. Our concern with this approach is that sometime over the years source control will be moved and we will lose the history. It also seems difficult to know what to look for to recover if we can't see all the dropped objects.
2. Leaving the .sql files in source control but updating the definitions to "drop proc {someproc}". With this approach we our concerned about leaving the objects in version control which no longer exists and also the risk to losing the history if the vcs was moved
3. Creating a new repo for dropped objects and migrating .sql files to this repo once they have been dropped from SQL Server.

We're working in a windows environment and are fairly new to working with VCS for databases. Currently GIT + SSDT.

Currently option 3 is our preferred approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this a lot with database code, what happens is over time people end up with stuff in the database that is either not used or just does not work (think a proc that references a table and the table is modified but not the proc).

The thing to do is to get everything in source control (which it looks like you have) and then create a tag or branch of all the code before and after deleting it so you can get it back.

Two things normally transpire, either the code was genuinely never used or it was used at year end and when you find out, the world is about to fall on your head so better have a quick way to get it back.

Of course if you had a full suite of tests then even the year end process would be safe :)

I personally wouldn't use option 3, I would just keep the history in the main branch so you keep the history with it.

ed

Comment: Thanks, I think with the tag this makes sense: 1. create branch to drop objects, 2. merge branch back to trunk with a tag, 3. drop branch. Assuming i trust that someone wont destroy all the vcs history then i can see this working. My final concern with option 1 is in 2 years time if some new devs want to resurrect the removed functionality how do they know what to search for to find the objects they need? With option 3. they can just read all the proc names in the 'dropped object' repo.

Comment: How about "git log --diff-filter=D --summary"

Comment: You can also snapshot the DB Project and store those so you have references, but I think combining that with deleting the objects or marking them as "Build Action = None" would be your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for the information. really helpful. We have decided to go with option 1 + option 3 as an insurance policy.

Comment: cool, it would be great to hear how you get on after a few months or if you change to using another approach :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good tools for versioning database changes: you have a big chance to get this question closed with "Too broad" reason, but I'll try to suggest to

- Read about, understand and try to add [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) to your Development-Toolbox
- Adopt your workflow for using this additional layer - technically it will be one more file (changelog in terms of Liquibase) in changesets, where you changing DD and|or data.
- These changelogs provide good and smooth way of moving back and forth in linear history of changes in databases, not so good (or I don't know The Right Way) for direct jumping between nodes of diverged history, but it seems not your case

From your options-list it will be more p.1, than others (but it's storing *changes* in database in version-contol, *not states*)

Answer (score 0):

Just to note another option, in SSDT you can mark the file property as Build Action = None. The file won't be included in the dacpac when this build option is selected. But I tend to agree with the idea that you should rely on your VCS to handle history.